# Why does the church have seven-branched candelabra?

Tags: le-chevalier-d-eon

In the first episode, d'Eon asks a woman about the "nqm" motif and is directed to go to a church to read the "Psalm of Vengeance" in the "ancient tongue" (i.e. Hebrew). While he is there, we see two seven-branched candelabra on the table.

[image: still with candlesticks]

This was strange to me, since the menorah, a *Jewish* symbol, was the first object I associated with "seven-branched candelabra." My internet searches did not clarify this:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menorah_(Temple)#In_other_cultures) suggests that the Orthodox church uses the menorah in liturgy, but *Le Chevalier d'Eon* takes place in France, where Western Christianity predominates.
- While I found a number of results that mentioned menorot in churches, I was not given much reason to believe that this was *traditional* practice.

  - I did find [this forum post](http://web.archive.org/web/20160720055638/http://www.catholic-forum.com/forums/showthread.php?59615-Milan-Cathedral-Menorah). The Google Translate version of [the Wikipedia page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candelabro_Trivulzio) linked suggests that ornate versions of such candelabra were common in the medieval period. However, I cannot tell from this whether they were still common by the period in which *Le Chevalier d'Eon* is set or whether smaller versions were ever at all common.
- I searched for images of seven-branched candelabra; the results were largely Judaism-related.

Is there any in-universe reason (whether specific to *Le Chevalier d'Eon*, or related to its setting) why such candelabra are being used?

Comment: There's one more issue that comes to mind (why does it seem that these candles are being used so frivolously, _if_ they're indeed supposed to be menorot?) but I'll leave that for now as I'm unsure of the specifics and would have to sit on it.

Comment: `This was strange to me, since the menorah, a Jewish symbol`. The Protestant Christian church  I attended as a child also contained both a seven and 9 branched candelbra. I was told this was to show were our roots lay, such a symbolism might be applied here as well.